Stuck in induction proof.
Proof of the binomial theorem by induction.

$$ (a + b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k} b^k(hypothesis) $$

$$ (a + b)^{m+1} = a(a + b)^m + b(a + b)^m $$
Under the induction hypothesis,
$$ a(a + b)^m = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} a^{m+1-k} b^k 
= a^{m+1} + \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{m}{k} a^{m+1-k} b^k $$
and
$$ b(a + b)^m = \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}{j} a^{m-j} b^{j+1} 
= \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{m}{k-1} a^{m+1-k} b^k + b^{m+1}. $$
but I'm getting $a^{m+1}$ as when $j=0$, as the term to be added is $a^{m-0+1}$ and  $b^{0-1+1}$.

$$ b(a + b)^m = \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}{j} a^{m-j} b^{j+1} 
= \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{m}{k-1} a^{m+1-k} b^k + a^{m+1}. $$
(Forgive the transition from j to k, it's in my book)

Why am i getting this? What can be done instead?

You can use the fact that for any sequence ${s_k}$, you have $\sum_{k=0}^n s_k = \sum_{k=0}^n s_{n-k}$ and apply it to your specific case.

The change of indices $k:=j+1$ leads to$$\sum_{j=0}^m\binom mja^{m-j}b^{j+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\binom m{k-1}a^{m+1-k}b^k=\sum_{k=1}^m\binom m{k-1}a^{m+1-k}b^k+b^{m+1}.$$
Your last equality is false for two reasons:
the term corresponding to $j=0$ stays in $\sum_{k=1}^m$ corresponding to $k=1$, and it is not $a^{m+1}$ but $a^mb$ (which is more reasonable, since when expanding $b(a+b)^m$, there must be at least one factor $b$ in each monomial).

Please don't answer duplicate questions. See here.

I am aware of the standards, and as far as I know this question is not a duplicate. It is not about "how to prove the binomial theorem by induction" (which I am not describing at all) but very specifically "where is my mistake in this proof?" (which I am explaining in full detail).

Why the change of indices though? Makes it all the more confusing, but i get it now. Thanks. @AnneBauval

This change of indices in $b(a+b)^m$ is necessary, to group each monomial except $b^{m+1}$ with the (now!) corresponding monomial in $a(a+b)^m$.
